# Count number of documents with $where in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am trying to make an `api` call with `axios` and `expressjs` in the backend that returns `count` of the `documents` for a given `condition`

But I don't know how to do that with `$where` clause and `countDocuments()` to access `MongoDB` with express.

Here is how my `backend` code looks like. Here I haven't used `$where` since I don't know how to do that.

> **I need something with `MongoDB` that returns document count where `isNewCourse = true`**

`isNewCourse` is a boolean field

```
//get courses count to-be accepted
router.route("/courses").get((req, res) => {
  CourseDB.countDocuments({}, function(err, count) {
    res.status(200).send(`${count}`);
  });
});
```

This code gives all the documents count, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    CourseDB.countDocuments({ isNewCourse: true })
```

No need for `$where`.

Comment: is `count()` depreciated now?